# Workbox применение

Tags: pwa, workbox

Изучаю PWA, столкнулся с таким инструментом, как Workbox. Почитал оф документацию и возник один вопрос. Правильно ли я понял, что Workbox отвечает только за облегчения кеширования, а другие фичи PWA как пуши и bg sync я должен реализовывать в сервис воркере самостоятельно? Или я что-то упустил?